# JAVA-OpenCV: Video Writer not opening

Tags: java, android, opencv, video-capture

I want to save the video I'm capturing with opencv in Android and I've chosen to use the openCV VideoWriter class (if there's a better way for Android please let me know).

The problem is that I'm not being capable of opening the object.

This is what I'm trying

```
videoWriter = new VideoWriter("saved_video.avi", VideoWriter.fourcc('M','J','P','G'),
            25.0D, new Size(mOpenCvCameraView.getWidth(),mOpenCvCameraView.getHeight()));
videoWriter.open("saved_video.avi", VideoWriter.fourcc('M','J','P','G'),
            25.0D,  new Size(mOpenCvCameraView.getWidth(),mOpenCvCameraView.getHeight()));
```

I keep getting videoWriter.isOpened()=false when it should be true.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the video path! It should be fully stated, like:

```
pathSavedVideoFolder = getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath(); 
filenameRawVideo = pathSavedVideoFolder + "/SavedVideo.avi";
```

After this you just need to refresh in order to see the file inside "Android/data/YOUR PROJECT/files" folder.